# Why does solidity not throw an error when I try to .call.value() without actually calling it?

Tags: solidity

If I do

`msg.sender.call.value(1 ether);`

It looks like I will send msg.sender 1 ether where I want to execute the fallback function.

However, it does NOT call it because I did not provide the brackets () for the arguments.

Why is this valid syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'll get a good answer to this "why" question, unless someone who worked on the early design of Solidity can chime in with their rationale.

Note that the following code also compiles:

```
function test() pure internal { }
function test2() pure internal {
    test;
    5;
}
```

Just like in your example, `test;` is valid syntactically but has no effect. No compiler warning is emitted.

Interestingly, the line `5;` *does* emit a warning: "Statement has no effect." This means the compiler does have some ability to recognize this sort of situation. I think that leaves the door open to a future version of the compiler emitting a warning for `test;` or your original example (which I believe is equivalent). I'm not convinced it should be a syntax error, but a warning seems quite reasonable.

If you'd like to see this changed, I would encourage you to open an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

**smarx** is right: your syntax is perfectly valid just because it does not translate into nothing in the bytecode side, so there's no real error in there.

Try to remove that line and the compiled byte code will result exactly the same.

You can see it as a syntax that produce an *unintended comment*. Why? Essentially because, even if it is improving fast, **Solidity is still a language in its very early stage** (currently latest release is the 0.4.24).